# EF 6 How to skip existing tables when generating migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to use code-first within my existing project. I want to exclude existing entities from migrations I generate for new entities.

I have all models in separate class library project e.g. Data.Models and I am intending to use one context by creating another class library e.g. Infra.EF (model project is referenced in it).

This is how my DbContext looks like:

```
    public DbSet<ExistingEntityOne> DataOfEntityOne { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExistingEntityTwo> DataofEntityTwo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NewEntity> NewData { get; set; }
```

Sorry if question isn't clear but I can add more information based on your feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you planning to generate new entities to a new database by creating new data context ?

Comment: Database will not change. So I do have a few models and their associated entities created in DB. Just struggling to generate migration for new entities.

Comment: `Just struggling to generate migration for new entities`, generating new entities to new database, correct?

Comment: I already have a database that has entities (that were created with their respective DBContexts in past). Now I am trying to use just one DBContext for any existing and new entities for simplicity. But database is an existing one. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is that the new DBContext or the _Existing Entities_ ?

Comment: That's new DBContext with both existing and new entities. In past, each entity had its own context, which was horrible :)

Comment: And you want to be able to use New DBContext by applying new changes (in this case I assume NewData is the new entity) to existing database ?

Comment: Exactly. I want to exclude existing entities when I do add-migration

Comment: Could you confirm one more thing, what is the existing dbcontext name? what is the project name that has existing dbcontext? does the project name that has existing dbcontext have connection string key? what is the name of the new db context? what is the project name that has new dbcontext?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Remove Migration directory from your project.
2. Comment new entities in your new `DbContext`.

   ```
   public DbSet<ExistingEntityOne> DataofEntityOne { get; set; }
   public DbSet<ExistingEntityTwo> DataofEntityTwo { get; set; }
   //public DbSet<NewEntity> NewData { get; set; }
   ```
3. Run following commands In power console manager:

   ```
   Enable-Migrations
   Add-Migration somename -IgnoreChanges
   ```
4. uncomment, commented entities.

   ```
   public DbSet<ExistingEntityOne> DataofEntityOne { get; set; }
   public DbSet<ExistingEntityTwo> DataofEntityTwo { get; set; }
   public DbSet<NewEntity> NewData { get; set; }
   ```
5. Run following command:

   ```
   Add-Migration someOtherName
   ```

You can find more, for EF Migrations [here](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Enable-Migrations)

Comment: It generated a blank migration file. However my model project does have a new model class which isn't in database.

Comment: @FaisalFareed: Is your new entity, in a separate DbContext?

Comment: DbContext is just one for all entities (existing and new).

Comment: @FaisalFareed: you could comment new entities in your DbContext, run above commands, then uncomment commented entities, and then run normal Add-migration someothername.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip any of the migrations (in my case, the initial migration included the generation of tables that already existed), you can comment the code or leave it blank:

```
namespace ShareDLL.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class NameOfMigrationToSkip : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) { }
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) { }
    }
}
```

Then start a full or point-in-time migration that includes the commented migration:

```
update-database
```

This will generate the migration entries "NameOfMigrationToSkip" in the __EFMigrationsHistory table, for example:

[image: example of migration history]

And restore/uncomment migration.